# Attachment_fu failing to validate on update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attachment-fu

I have been using attachment_fu on a project for a long time and all was fine but now as I am trying to bring the project up to rails 2.3.3 I am running into a strange bug that is driving me nuts. The Attachment, a logo in this case, validates correctly on create but does not fail validation on update. I have debugged it and it fails the intial validate but does not seem to throw an exception or at least not one that is caught by my rescue in the controller. Seems like I have tried everything but can't figure this one out.

Controller:

```
  # POST /tournaments
  # POST /tournaments.xml
  def create
    # Build tournament
    @tournament = Tournament.new(params[:tournament].merge(:user_id => current_user.id) )

    # Save the uploaded attachments
    params[:uploads].each do |upload|
      @tournament.documents << Document.new({:uploaded_data => upload[:document]}.merge(:description => upload[:description]))
    end unless params[:uploads].nil?

    # if supplied save an event logo
    @logo = Logo.new({:uploaded_data => params[:logo][:upload_data]}) unless params[:logo].nil? or params[:logo][:upload_data].blank?  
    @tournament.logo = @logo unless @logo.nil?     

    respond_to do |format|
      begin
        Tournament.transaction do    
          @tournament.logo.save! unless @tournament.logo.nil?
          @tournament.save!  
        end
        flash[:notice] = 'Tournament was successfully created.'
        format.html { redirect_to tournament_url(@tournament) }
        format.xml  { head :created, :location => tournament_url(@tournament) }        
      rescue 
          flash[:notice] = 'Errors prevented your Tournament from being saved'
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @tournament.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /tournaments/1
  # PUT /tournaments/1.xml
  def update
    @tournament = Tournament.find(params[:id])
    @tournament.user_id = session[:orig_user_id]

    respond_to do |format|
      begin
        Tournament.transaction do   
          # Update Logo if necessary
          unless params[:logo][:upload_data].blank?
            @tournament.logo.destroy unless @tournament.logo.nil?
            @tournament.logo = Logo.new({:uploaded_data => params[:logo][:upload_data]}.merge(:user_id => current_user.id)) 
          end   
          # Save any uploaded documents
          params[:uploads].each do |upload|
            @tournament.documents << Document.new({:uploaded_data => upload[:document]}.merge(:description => upload[:description]))
          end unless params[:uploads].nil?   
          # Update Tournamnet Attributes
          @tournament.attributes = params[:tournament]  
          # Save the Tournament
          @tournament.save!         
        end
        flash[:notice] = 'Tournament was successfully updated.' 
        format.html { redirect_to tournament_url(@tournament) }
        format.xml  { head :ok, :location => tournament_url(@tournament) }        
      rescue 
          flash[:notice] = 'Errors prevented your Tournament from being updated' 
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @tournament.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Logo Model:

```
    class Logo < Asset    

  validate_on_create :attachment_valid? 

  has_attachment :content_type => :image, 
    :storage => :file_system, 
    :max_size => 4.megabytes,
    :resize_to => '810x150>',  
    :processor  => :ImageScience,
    :thumbnails => { :thumb => '270x50>'  }  


  def attachment_valid? 
    content_type = attachment_options[:content_type] 
    unless content_type.nil? || content_type.include?(self.content_type) 
      errors.add(:upload_data, " * must be an image file (jpg, gif, or png)")  
    end 
    size = attachment_options[:size] 
    unless size.nil? || size.include?(self.size)               
      errors.add(:upload_data, "* image must be 4MB or less")  
    end   
  end 


  before_thumbnail_saved do |thumbnail|
    record = thumbnail.parent
    thumbnail.user_id = record.user_id 
    thumbnail.listing_id = record.listing_id
  end

end
```

I am running the following

Rails 2.3.3

image_science 1.2.0

Thanks 
--Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use a :before_save callback to test the object. If it is invalid, raise an exception.

Comment: This seems to be the best way to go

Comment: By raising a RecordInvalid exception in my custom validation and moving the assignment of the logo to the tournamnet into the transaction block I was able to get this working. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

try adding:

```
validate_on_update :attachment_valid?
```